# How to track people detected by hog descriptor

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.0

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main ()
{
VideoCapture cap("/opencv/images/people.avi");
if (!cap.isOpened())
    return -1;

Mat img;
HOGDescriptor hog;
hog.setSVMDetector(HOGDescriptor::getDefaultPeopleDetector());

namedWindow("video capture", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
while (true)
{
    cap >> img;
    if (!img.data)
        continue;

    vector<Rect> found, found_filtered;
    hog.detectMultiScale(img, found, 0, Size(8,8), Size(32,32), 1.05, 2);

    size_t i, j;
    for (i=0; i<found.size(); i++)
    {

        Rect r = found[i];
        for (j=0; j<found.size(); j++)
            if (j!=i && (r & found[j])==r)
                break;
        if (j==found.size())
            found_filtered.push_back(r);
    }
    for (i=0; i<found_filtered.size(); i++)
    {
                        Rect r = found_filtered[i];
                        Point textOrg(r.x,r.y);
                        r.x += cvRound(r.width*0.1);
                        r.width = cvRound(r.width*0.8);
                        r.y += cvRound(r.height*0.07);
                        r.height = cvRound(r.height*0.8);
                        rectangle(img, r.tl(), r.br(), Scalar(0,255,0), 3);
                        putText(img, "human", textOrg,
                                        FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 0.8, Scalar::all(000), 1, CV_AA);

}
    imshow("video capture", img);
    if (waitKey(20) >= 0)
    {  break;}
}

return 0;
}
```

above code can used to detect people in every frame using hog. But I want to track those people for action recognition.I hope to use dense optical flow for action recognition.Can I us hog descriptor for tracking or is there any other good method.

Comment: read about "tracking by detection" and "probabilistic tracking". Simple tracking by optical flow might or might not be applicable, try it... I would recommend "particle filtering" (condensation)

Comment: openCV 3 has TLD tracking integrated, you might want to try it.